# Is a push-fit end cap a temporary or permanent solution?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I am about to cap my water copper pipe with a Sharkbite push fit end cap. Is it a permanent solution? Or will I have to go with a torch?

Answer (score 1):

They are meant to be a permanent solution, at least I hope so, I used them in my master bath renovation to convert from PVC to copper. Real easy solution, follow install guidelines.